# Permission error when trying to pass Content Uri from activity to service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-fileprovider, android-intentservice

I have an activity which accepts `android.intent.action.SEND`.
It accepts some media files and texts.
As it accepts a new 'share' it does some validation checks and pass the Uri to a service, it looks like this:

```
Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ShareService.class)
        .setData(uri)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) // probably redundant but harmless here       
        .putParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.EXTRA_SHARE_FILES, uris)
startService(serviceIntent);
```

It works for all `file` providers and usually for `content` as well, but from time to time I get reports of failures:

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10283 does not have permission to content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/33560 [user 0]
```

Is there anything I can do to keep the Uri permission alive? how should I handle this kind of Uri?

Comment: `probably redundant but harmless here` -- actually, it is essential. Beyond that, what is `uris`?

Comment: Correct, I actually added the comment when writing the question and I was wrong. Since multiple files share are also handled by the same service, I set `uris` as `ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>(1);
            uris.add(uri);` and on the receiving service I use them: `ArrayList<Uri> attachments = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.EXTRA_SHARE_FILES);`

Comment: AFAIK, `Uri` values in arbitrary extras are not covered by `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`. That covers the `data` facet of the `Uri`, and covers certain extras on certain actions (kinda hard-coded in the framework).

Comment: The `Uri` in the extras is the same as in the `data`, it's just easier to pass and parse. It's in production and actually works for thousands of `Uri`'s but here and there I see a similar error message

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misinterpreted your previous comment. Is there a scenario where your activity might have finished before the service starts, perhaps? I don't know how the permission grant works in that sort of edge case.

Comment: The activity just starts the service and finishes itself. I'm not exactly sure how exactly `startService()` works and if it's sync/async call so I can't really answer. I can only assume it's async and it's a race condition but even in this case, when looking over 'big numbers' it works 99.999% of the times

Comment: `startService()` is definitely async. You might want to see if you can rig up a way to keep the activity around until the service has started and the `Uri` handoff is complete. Also, going back to my earlier comment... "Since multiple files share are also handled by the same service" -- how do you know that the problem is coming from *this* `startService()` call and not the multiple-files one?

Comment: These are 2 separate methods and the exception is coming from the method handling the single file (from within the `startService()` call), I wasn't actually able to reproduce this, I've tried sharing file and get `content` Uri but I get only `file`, any idea which app I can use to send `content` Uri?

Comment: Anything on Android 7.0+ should be using `content` `Uri` values. Personally, I'd toss together a scrap app that had `FileProvider` and initiated the `ACTION_SEND`, just so I control both sides of the communications.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll give it a shot and report back. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192684/discussion-between-sagilow-and-commonsware).

Comment: Sorry, since I offer chats as part of my Warescription, I don't do Stack Overflow chats, as that would be weird.

Comment: That's perfectly fine. Anyway, I wasn't able to reproduce it. I've changed the activity to do `moveTaskToBack` instead of `finish()`, let's see how that goes

Comment: @SagiLow have you figure out what the issue was?

Answer (score -2):

please create xml folder in your app and in xml mentioned file provider file and network security configure file after that declare fileprovider in AndroidMenifest.xml file

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it doesn't seem to be the correct answer in this case